# Usando IF e UPDATE em uma PROCEDURE para atualizar uma tabela

Tags: sql, pl-sql, procedure

Sou novo em SQL e PLSQL e estou tendo dificuldade com a seguinte situação:

create or replace PROCEDURE set_valor(p_variavel VARCHAR2, p_valor VARCHAR2) IS

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO co_t_conf (nome_variavel,valor_variavel) values (p_variavel, p_valor);
    
     --Eu preciso atualizar o nome_variavel se o valor p_variavel inserido for um valor 
       já existente na tabela co_t_conf. Como posso usar um IF e um UPDATE nessa situação?

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Você avaliou o uso do `UPSERT`?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
v_tem number;    
BEGIN
        select 1 into v_tem from co_t_conf where p_variavel = chave_da_tabela;
        
        if v_tem then 
        UPDATE 
        else
        INSERT
        end if;
         --Eu preciso atualizar o nome_variavel se o valor p_variavel inserido for um valor 
         --já existente na tabela co_t_conf. Como posso usar um IF e um UPDATE nessa situação?
    
        COMMIT;
    END;
```

Primeiro da um select na tabela e verifica se o cara já existe, joga ele numa váriavel, se vir o cara faz um if passando update, se não vir ele faz o insert dele...

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma , se tenta alterar , se nada for afetado se Insere.

```
BEGIN
    -- supondo nome_variavel a PK data tabela
    UPDATE co_t_conf SET valor_variavel = p_valor
    WHERE nome_variavel = p_variavel;
    IF sql%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN --LINHAS AFETADAS
      INSERT INTO co_t_conf (nome_variavel,valor_variavel) values (p_variavel, p_valor);
    END IF;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

O mais correto no seu caso, seria utilizar o comando `MERGE`. Ele trata exatamente isso que você esta tentando fazer.

Basicamente ele funciona assim:

Você faz `JOIN` da tabela principal com ela mesmo buscando os dados da chave.
Caso este join encontre alguma coisa, você pode atualizar os valores, do contrário, poderá inseri-los.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE set_valor(p_variavel VARCHAR2, p_valor VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN  

  MERGE INTO co_t_conf t1
       USING (SELECT chave_da_tabela 
                FROM co_t_conf 
               WHERE nome_variavel = p_variavel) t2
          ON (t1.chave_da_tabela     = t2.chave_da_tabela)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE 
             SET nome_variavel  = p_variavel
                ,valor_variavel = p_valor
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (nome_variavel,
                  valor_variavel)
          VALUES (p_nome_variavel,
                  p_valor_variavel);
                  
END;
```

A documentação sobre este comando pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement).